# How to set image for UIBarButtonItem Flexible space - IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

Have a look at this image...

[image]

I want to design toolbar like this, Each UIBarButtonItem should be separated by a thin line. So I have inserted flexible space button in between each UIBarButtonItem (that helps me in aligning UIBarButtonItem while orientation changes), however if I set an image for that, its no more acting as flexible button, changes to normal UIBarbutton.

So I need an flexible space button with an image.. Any idea how to do it.
(OR)
How to design a UIToolbar like above... Any helps is really appreciated. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

To set background image for UIBarbuttonItem

```
UIImage *faceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook.png"];
UIButton *face = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
face.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, faceImage.size.width, faceImage.size.height );
[face setImage:faceImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *faceBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:face];
```

Comment: It will works if it is a normal UIBarButtonItem, It is not working for  UIBarButtonItem-flexible space button.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you..

```
UIImage* topImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBarGradient.png"];

// Create a new image context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(width, topImage.size.height*2), NO, 0.0);

// Create a stretchable image for the top of the background and draw it
UIImage* stretchedTopImage = [topImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
[stretchedTopImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, topImage.size.height)];

// Draw a solid black color for the bottom of the background
[[UIColor blackColor] set];
CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, topImage.size.height, width, topImage.size.height));

// Generate a new image
UIImage* resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return resultImage;
```

and for more detail you can check this...

http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/04/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar/

If didn't solve your problem..let me know..

Comment: Sure, I will try and let you know.